# error in c# program while copying into a database

Tags: c#, database, forms, syntax

```
namespace DB1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String query="INSERT INTO  Student 
            VALUES("+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"',
            '"+textBox4.Text+")";

            OleDbConnection conn = new 
            OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
            Data Source=C:\\Database11.accdb");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query,conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("data stored succesfully");
            conn.Close();
            textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + 1).ToString();
            textBox2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) + 1).ToString();
            textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) + 1).ToString();
            textBox4.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text) + 1).ToString();
            textBox1.Focus();

        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            autonum();
        }

        private void autonum()
        {
            string query;

            query = "Select max(Stdno) from student";
            OleDbConnection conn = new      
            OleDbConnection("Provider=Micrsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
            Data Source=datasource");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query,conn);
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
             OleDbDataReader dr =cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if(dr.Read())
                {
                    textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(dr[0])+1).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.Text="1001";
                }

                dr.Close();
            }
        catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
               textBox1.Text = "1001";
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

error is:

> oledb exception was unhandled Syntax error (missing operator) in query
>   expression '2','wse','22','assd'.

Comment: You've given *two* queries here - why? Presumably only one of them is failing. Please show *where* it's failing. Additionally, your code is currently vulnerable to SQL injection attacks - please use parameterized SQL.

Comment: format messy code, write everything about error at least where you getting it, write question. then maybe anyone try to help you.

Comment: the question is to store information of a student into a ms acess database using c#,the error is cmd.ExceuteNonQuery

Answer (score 5):

Don't use string concetanation to build your query. Use parameters instead:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Student VALUES (@P1, @P2, @P3, @P4)";
// ...
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@P1", textBox1.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@P2", textBox2.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@P3", textBox3.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@P4", textBox4.Text));
```

I'd also recommend:

- Explicitly list the columns in your insert statement.
- Use descriptive names for your text boxes.

Comment: Are you editing to show what the new query would look like too?

Answer (score 2):

I second the notion that you should always used parameters otherwise you leave your database open. 
For example,

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column='" + var _+"'";
```

can become

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column='';SELECT 'i can hack you if you do this'
```

Parameters prevent this from happening.

Comment: +1 for giving an example of how the SQL injection might look like.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted you because this is one of the very basic standard errors people that just not know what they do do all the time.

Your problem is the way you put the strings from the textboxes into the SQL string.

First, there is an error - and you should know that by looking at the SQL you generate.

```
...Student VALUES("+textBox1.Text+"'...
```

this is missing a ' before the first ", sorry. BLABLA as text turns into

```
VALUES(BLABLA'
```

which is illegal sql.

Instead of coming here you should just have had a look at the value of the query variable AFTER you assign it - easy to do in the debugger and you can see that you are not forming the SQL you think you are forming.

Second, if any of your text boxes contain a ' you are literally doomed - and this is the nice way to say it (any moderator feeling this is inappropriate please redact out the word). I can inject any arbitrary SQL I want by manipulating our text boxes, this is called SQL injection attack. Read up on it ("SQL Injection" as keyword for google) and then fix it and use parameters. Always. The way you do it gets you fired in some project groups for not knowing how to write safe SQL code.